# Javascript loading images

Tags: javascript, image

I am using the following on an image

```
image.addEventListener("load",imageLoaded,false);
```

Is this the same as

```
image.onLoad = function(){
   imageLoaded();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one should be `onload` instead of `onLoad`. If you're asking if they'll both invoke the handler when the image is loaded, then yes.

If there are no additional arguments to pass, you could shorten the second one...

```
image.onload = imageLoaded;
```

A key difference is that you can bind multiple handlers using `addEventListener`, but just one with `onload`.

Comment: Thanks it was the answer I was looking for.